# I am having http status 404 while running my jsp which is linked to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my jsp code:-

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>  
        <div id="header">
            <center>
                <div id="over">
                    <p> <font size="18" color="Brown"><b>UBONA Technologies</b></font></p>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <form method="get" action="controller.java">
           <div class="container">
           <center>
            <table tableborder=0>
                  <tr><td><label><font size="5" color="BLACK"><b>USERNAME</b></font></label></td>
                  <br>
                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="username" class="inputi" required></td>
                  </tr><br>
                  <tr><td><label><font size="5" color="BLACK"><b>PASSWORD</b></font></label></td>
                  <br>
                  <td><input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" class="inputi" required></td>
                  </tr><br>
                  </table><br>
                  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="LOGIN" />      
            </center></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my Servlets code :-

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

//@WebServlet("/controller")
public class controller extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {                     
        }
        try 
        {  
            String uname = request.getParameter("username");
            String paswd = request.getParameter("password");
            Connection con= null;
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","6q190No6@");
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select * from credentials");
            rs.next();
            String username1 = rs.getString("username");
            String password2 = rs.getString("password"); 
            if(uname.equals(username1) && paswd.equals(password2))
            { 
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp"); 
            } 
            else
            {
                response.sendRedirect("wrongpas.jsp");
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqe)
        {
            System.out.println("home"+sqe);
        }

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

    }

}
```

this is my web.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

- I have changed the location of tomcat server as suggested in some videos.
- As I saw some replies to the same question which were saying that save class to the root folder/ web-inf/classes i am unable to find that folder too.

Comment: In form action attribute you have to give url not the file name

Comment: The url-pattern and action attribute value must be same

Comment: If you don't have WEB-INF/classes create one. Put your class into it and reload the thing. Also if your servlet is in a package (which is good practice) you have to add the package name in web.xml too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have `WEB-INF/classes` create it manually and save your class there.

Put your needed jars into `WEB-INF/lib/`.

First modify your form tag to

```
<form id="login" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller" method="GET">
```

Add id attribute

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="username" id="username" class="inputi" required>
```

also in here

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="username" class="inputi" required>
```

Second remove your comment on annotation

```
//@WebServlet("/controller")
```

Make it

```
@WebServlet(name = "controller", urlPatterns = {"/controller"})
```

Import annotations

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
```

Remove `doPost` it does nothing in your case.

You don't need `web.xml` also.

**Recommends**

Your class name should start with capital letter.

urlPatterns should be different from your class name.

Answer (score 0):

Following changes will resolve your issue:

In JSP code:

```
<form role="form" method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller">
```

In Servlet code:

```
@WebServlet("/controller")
```

Adding above line of code will prompt you to import Webservlet annotations library:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
```

Also it is considered a good practice to begin Java class names with Uppercase 
i.e ***c***ontroller.java should be ***C***ontroller.java